Is there a way to program a two-step Detectron2 mechanism?
I have a fossil tooth classifier, and I would like to program it in a two-step fashion, where in the first round, it detects the species, and in the second round it detects the position of the tooth in the mouth. I want the second round only to operate on the instances where the precision is above a certain threshold. Is this possible?
I currently have a one-step mechanism which works fine, but I'm looking for a 2step one.
